# Virtualbox How to prevent guest to not using my VPN connection?

Tags: virtualbox, vpn

Host: Windows 10

Guest: Windows 7

Virtualbox: 6.1.2

I dont want to share my VPN connection with guest machine but when i check my ipaddress on that it always picking up my VPN ip, This is my network settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the VM network to Bridged mode instead of NAT, the VM actually will obtain
a unique IP address from the DHCP server on the network.

In this case, the VM is separate from the host, acting as another computer
on the network that is distinct from the host.

The VM would then not go through the VPN (unless the VPN is entered on the router).
The host using a VPN would not affect the VM, which will connect directly to the
router in Bridged mode.